# How to select distinct trees from a table where there is a 1-to-1 relationship between trees and structures?

Tags: sql

I have a table called `Checks` like this:

```
treeId   checkId
 1       2
 1       4
 2       4
 2       5
```

I want to select the distinct trees where 
checkId is in [1, 2, 3]
and checkId is in [4,5]

So the result should return just 1

What I have:

```
Select * FROM Checks
WHERE checkId IN (1, 2, 3)
AND checkId IN (4, 5)
```

But that returns no results

**Update:**

1. Get the treeIds that are in [1,2, 3], returns output set
2. From the output set select trees that are in [4, 5] creates outputset2

Should only return `1`

**Extra**

What if there are more conditions, say:

3. From outputset2, select trees that are in [6,7]

Comment: You mean `treeID in (1,2,3) and checkid IN (4,5)` ?

Comment: I'm guessing that he needs treeIds that have at least one of 1,2 or 3 and at least one of 4 and 5 - i.e. if treeId has only checkId 1 and 3 (for instance), it's not required in the returned data.

Comment: Hey guys, I have updated the question for clarity

Comment: Still there are confusion b/w `treeID` and `checkID`. Query shows `checkID` and ur update shows `treeID`. can u clarify?

Comment: In your update can you please add more description about second point especially when you are saying "select trees that are"

Comment: What you mean is that you want the list of unique `treeId` that have at least one row with a `checkId` in [1,2,3] and at least one row with a `checkId` in [4,5] ?

Comment: @Pholochtairze 100% correct

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

This will give you `treeid`'s that have at least 1 `checkID` of 4,5 and at least 1 `checkID` of 1,2,3:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.treeid
FROM Checks c1
where (select count(c2.checkid) from Checks c2 where c2.checkID in (4,5) and c2.treeid=c1.treeid) > 0
and (select count(c2.checkid) from Checks c2 where c2.checkID in (1,2,3) and c2.treeid=c1.treeid) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should answer your need [see sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/ad3e6/1/0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    treeId
FROM Checks c1
WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Checks c2 WHERE c1.treeId = c2.treeId AND c2.checkId IN (1,2,3))
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Checks c2 WHERE c1.treeId = c2.treeId AND c2.checkId IN (4,5))
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Checks c2 WHERE c1.treeId = c2.treeId AND c2.checkId IN (6,7));
```

To add another condition, if `a,b,c,d,e` are your new conditions, just add a new condition with this

```
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Checks c2 WHERE c1.treeId = c2.treeId AND c2.checkId IN (a,b,c,d,e));
```